# Ruby 1.8.7 / Rails 2.3.4 - How does request.host look like in an IPv6 environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ipv6

We are currently doing local IP address detection (using ifconfig, tracepath etc.) in Rails to reach a charting application hosted on the same machine as Rails. The 'self IP address' is detected during Rails start-up and is done only once. Assuming that a user can reach the Apache/Rails server using both hostname and IP address, can I safely use `request.host` (after user has logged into the application) to create a URL  in an `<img>` tag (which essentially is the image returned by the charting application) in both IPv4 and IPv6 environments? Currently it works for IPv4 addresses as shown below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    CHARTS_BASE = ''
    def set_chart_url
      chart_url = MYAPP_CONFIG["chart_base"]
      chart_url.gsub!("$chart_host", request.host)
      CHARTS_BASE.replace(chart_url + 'charts?')
    end

class ReportController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_chart_url
```

View:

```
<div>
  <img src="<%=CHARTS_BASE + @opt_graph-%>" alt="Graph"/>
</div>
```

Will the same work for IPv6? What does `request.host` look like in an IPv6 environment when connecting to Rails using hostname or IPv6 address in the URL?

I thought anyone already running Rails in an IPv6 environment could validate the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPv6 address is given, in brackets.

I just generated a simple hello world controller and added to its view:

```
<%= request.host %>
```

I then started up webrick with `rails server -b ::` and then visited `http://[2001:db8:38c3:1189:c8d3:210f:f297:ba13]:3000/` in my browser. The output was:

> Home#index
>
> Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb
>
> [2001:db8:38c3:1189:c8d3:210f:f297:ba13]

---

Note that `request.host` contains the content of the HTTP `Host` header. So you might see a hostname here, or an IPv4 address. In any case, you should be able to use it as-is to construct a URL.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know request.host can be used for IPv6 too. I was more interested in the brackets thing. One more question, is your Rails, 2.3.4 or 3.x? Does it matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter what Rails version. The brackets are there to distinguish the IPv6 literal from the colon which precedes the port number in the URL.

Comment: See [RFC 2732](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2732) for the reason that the brackets are there.